# Правильное текстурирование треугольников SFML (3д)

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, sfml

Я делаю свой `3д` движок и хочу текстурировать треугольники. Я знаю что так может `OpenGL`, но не знаю, как можно применить это в `SFML`. На данный момент текстурирование треугольников заключается в том, что я заполняю треугольник текстурой. При движении камеры куб (из треугольников) начинает "плыть", при отдалении от треугольника текстура очень сильно уменьшается (так, что саму текстуру не видно, только какой-то шум) + если подойти близко, можно увидеть, что текстура на грань куба не одна (так как 2 треугольника на грань), можете подсказать, как можно внедрить `OpenGL` и решить проблему или как-то поменять функцию заливки текстурой (когда я пытался сделать свою, ФПС падал до 0-3). Код отрисовки сейчас:

```cpp
void TextureTriangle(Texture textr, vec3 color, vec3 dot1, vec3 dot2, vec3 dot3, RenderWindow &wind){
    ConvexShape Triangle(3);
    Triangle.setPoint(0, sfvec(dot1));
    Triangle.setPoint(1, sfvec(dot2));
    Triangle.setPoint(2, sfvec(dot3));
    Triangle.setTexture(&textr);
    Triangle.setFillColor(sfcolor(color));
    wind.draw(Triangle);
}
```

`sfvec` - моя функция для конвертации из моего `vec3` в `sf::Vector2f` (формат `dotN` - {`x`, `y`, `0`})

`sfcolor` - моя функция для конвертации из моего `vec3` в `sf::Color`

Шум:
[image: 1]

Разные треугольники на одной гране (применяется отсечение ,так что треугольников > 2):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведен код, рисующий треугольник, а на картинке почему-то куб.  *"применяется отсечение"* - ¿какое еще отсечение? А об использовании opengl в SFML рассказывается в официальной документации.

Comment: @user7860670 "Отсечение" - clipping (обрезание треугольников вне фрустума и экрана для повышения производительности). Куб состоит из треугольников, в кубе их лучше всего видно. Как использовать OpenGL для отрисовки треугольников с текстурой я не понимаю

Comment: *"применяется отсечение ,так что треугольников > 2"* даже если под отсечением в первой половине фразы подразумевается clipping, то непонятно, какая связь со второй половиной это фразы, ведь clipping никаким образом не может увеличить количество треугольников.

Comment: @user7860670 Может, так как при отсечении могут образоваться многоугольники, а моим движком они не поддерживаются, так что они обрезаются в другие треугольники

Comment: Никакие многоугольники при отсечении не образуются. clipping в принципе не меняет геометрию. Что-то вы там непонятное мутите... В любом случае, без конкретного кода ничего определенного сказать нельзя.

Comment: @user7860670 Хорошо, нужен код отсечения?

Comment: Наверное стоит все-таки для начала разобраться с Opengl. Но вообще да, если что-то не работает, то в вопросе обязательно необходимо приводить [mcve], чтобы читающие имели возможность воспроизвести проблему у себя.

Comment: @user7860670 я отсечение упомянул лишь для того, что бы не было вопросов, а почему так много треугольников. Минимальный воспроизводимый пример уже есть, надо только сделать отрисовку  и обработку окна (и саму картинку "подключить"). Проблема именно в отрисовке